# Data structure to store unique <key,value> tuples, where <value> is the minimum

Tags: c++, data-structures, stdmap

I've to store in a data structures tuples of the type

```
<(1,1),10>
<(1,1),9>
<(2,1),5>
<(1,1),11>
```

And I need to have just

```
<(1,1),9>
<(2,1),5>
```

Which data structure best fit for this kind of problem in c++?

This is my current solution/workaround, i'll keep looking for a more elegant solution btw.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
using namespace std;



typedef pair<int, int> mapkey;
typedef boost::unordered_map<mapkey,float,boost::hash<mapkey> > hmap;
typedef hmap::iterator hitr;

class mymap
{
public:
    hmap map;
    void insert(std::pair<mapkey,float> p)
    {
        hmap::iterator i = map.find(p.first);
        if(i==map.end()){
            map.insert(p);
        }
        else{

            if(p.second<i->second){
                i->second=p.second;
            }
        }

    }
};


int main()
{


    mymap map;


    map.insert(std::make_pair(mapkey(1,1),10.0f));
    map.insert(std::make_pair(mapkey(1,2),22.0f));
    map.insert(std::make_pair(mapkey(2,1),22.0f));
    map.insert(std::make_pair(mapkey(1,1),5.0f));

        BOOST_FOREACH(hmap::value_type i, map.map) {
            mapkey m = i.first;
            std::cout <<"( "<<m.first<<" , "<< m.second<<" ) > " <<i.second<<endl;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why 9,5 and not 9,11 or 9,10?

Comment: @Mal you can use HashMap data structure.

Comment: @Mal What do you want? Could you descrip your question clearly?

Comment: thank you, i'm trying with boost unordered_map

Comment: @Jite i want to store for the same key the lowest value

Answer (score 0):

just a simple HashMap will do.

> Key- class having two attributes, suppose `i`, `j`
>
> value - always minimum i.e. a simple int

Answer (score 0):

A hash table, with a custom insert that inserts iff the key is previously unseen or the new value is less than the previous one.

Comment: i've completey no idea on how to define to define "custom insert that inserts iff the key is previously unseen or the new value is less than the previous one"

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashMap build-in class in C++. 
For you problem, just a simple customisation that you only need to enter  pair in HashMap if

1) Key doesn't exist or

2) If key exists, then compare old-value to new-value and then if new-value is less than old value then insert  pair in HashMap.

For your reference you can use [Simple HashMap implementation in C++](http://blog.aozturk.me/simple-hash-map-hash-table-implementation-in-c)